# How to get sharepoint user by account ID?

Tags: spservices

I only have access to account IDs. Ex 59206.

No access to user names.

How can I use SPservices to get the rest of the account information?

Answer (score 1):

2013

SP.Web.getUserById()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247179(v=office.15).aspx

or

spservices

`GetUserProfileByGuid` and `GetUserProfileByIndex` should work

http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UserProfileService

and another solution

http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/262196

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://info.global.Company.com/demo/OrgChart/Documents/peoplefunc.aspx?ID='+itemId,
    success: function(data) {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetUserProfileByName",
        AccountName: $(data).find('div').text()+'@Company.com',
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {                
             alert($(xData.responseXML).find("Name:contains('First')").parent().find('Value').text());
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The Ajax code piece is great way of getting the info direcly from Organization chart. But what if the Org chart is silverlight based & HTML is not configured for the view? just asking

Answer (score 0):

You could query User Information List to retrieve User details.

### How to get user information using SharePoint Web Services ([SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/))

```
function getUserInfo(userId,result)
{

  $().SPServices({
     operation: "GetListItems",
     listName: "User Information List",
     CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>" + userId + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
     CAMLRowLimit: 1,
     completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
         var userEntry = {};
         var row = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").get(0);
         userEntry.Name = $(row).attr("ows_Name");
         userEntry.Title = $(row).attr("ows_Title");
         userEntry.Email = $(row).attr("ows_Email");
         result(userEntry);
     }
  });
}


//Usage
getUserInfo(12,function(userEntry){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(userEntry));
});
```